# Python binary tree use build instead of Node

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
def printPaths(root): 
    path = []
    printPathsRec(root, path, 0)
def printPathsRec(root, path, pathLen):  
    if root is None:
        return
    if(len(path) > pathLen):
        path[pathLen] = root.data
    else:
        path.append(root.data)
    pathLen = pathLen + 1
    if root.left is None and root.right is None:
        printArray(path, pathLen)
    else:
    
        printPathsRec(root.left, path, pathLen)
        printPathsRec(root.right, path, pathLen)

def printArray(ints, len):
    for i in ints[0 : len]:
        print(i," ",end="")
    print()
 

from binarytree import build

values = [7, 3, 2, 6, 9, None, 1, 5, 8]
root = build(values)
print(root) 
printPaths(root.value)
.
```

I need to build binary tree with build and make the code work, but i can't find out the way.
This example is get from internet,they use method like

```
root = Node(10)
root.left = Node(8)
root.right = Node(2)
root.left.left = Node(3)
root.left.right = Node(5)
root.right.left = Node(2)
printPaths(root)
```

But i need to use another method to make it happen.

Comment: You're basically asking for the whole binary-tree building algorithm. `Node(<n>)` is just the constructor for a single node. You're presumably learning how to construct binary trees at this point, which is all about figuring out how to organize the nodes, it seems to defeat the learning exercise to ask for the solution here.

Comment: *"i need to use another method to make it happen"*: so what are the requirements? How does the list map to a tree? And what have you done to start coding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To create binary Tree:**

you need a list sequential.

```
class Node:
    count = 0
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.val = val
        Node.count+= 1
        
    def __str__(self):
        return (f"value is {self.val} \ncount is:{self.count}")
```

If info is given as:

```
from collections import deque

d = {0:[1,2], 2:[4,5], 1:[3]} # how nodes are connected. key is node number and values is node num of children.

vals = [10,11,12,13,14,15] # values associated with the node num

q = deque()
q.append(0) #<---- root node
li = [vals[0]] #<--- root node val
while(len(q)>0):
    front = q.popleft()
    
    if (d.get(front, 0)):
        if(len(d[front])==2):
            li.append(vals[d[front][0]])
            li.append(vals[d[front][1]])
            q.append(d[front][0])
            q.append(d[front][1])
        else:
            li.append(vals[d[front][0]])
            li.append(None)
            q.append(d[front][0])
#         q.append(d[front][1])
    else:
        li.append(None)
        li.append(None)
```

This will give you list

**li:**

```
[10, 11, 12, 13, None, 14, 15, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

---

**build:**

```
def build(values):
    if not values:
        return None
    it = iter(values)
    root=Node(next(it))
    q = deque()
    q.append(root)
    while(q):
        front = q.popleft()
        val1 = next(it, None)
        if (val1):
            n1 = Node(val1)
            q.append(n1)
            front.left = n1
            
        val2 = next(it, None)
        if (val2):
            n2 = Node(val2)
            q.append(n2)
            front.right = n2
    return root
    
node = build(li)
```

---

**To print in inorder:**

```
def print_node(root):
    if not root:
        return
    print_node(root.left)
    print(root.val, end=" ")
    print_node(root.right)
```

---

```
print_node(node)
```

---

> 13 11 10 14 12 15

### Straight Forward:

```
from collections import deque

d = {0:[1,2], 2:[4,5], 1:[3]}
vals = [10,11,12,13,14,15]


q = deque()
root = Node(vals[0], 0)
q.append(root)
while(q):
    node = q.popleft()
    if (d.get(node.node_num, {})):
        if(len(d[node.node_num])==2):
            no1 = d[node.node_num][0]
            node.left = Node(vals[no1],no1)
            no2 = d[node.node_num][1]
            node.right = Node(vals[no2], no2)
            q.append(node.left)
            q.append(node.right)
        else:
            no1 = d[node.node_num][0]
            node.left = Node(vals[no1],no1)
            q.append(node.left)

print_node(root)
```

> 13 11 10 14 12 15

Added 1 attribute for `node_num` in class `Node`

Answer (score 2):

I am going to guess that `values` contains the level-order values of the tree, where the children below a `None` are not included (instead of having two filler `None` values).

Then the algorithm to populate a new tree will *also* follow a level-order way of populating. For this you typically use a queue or deque or two lists. For example:

```
def build(values):
    if not values:
        return
    it = iter(values)
    root = Node(next(it))
    level = [root]
    while level:
        nextlevel = []
        for parent in level:
            value = next(it, None)
            if value is not None:
                parent.left = Node(value)
                nextlevel.append(parent.left)
            value = next(it, None)
            if value is not None:
                parent.right = Node(value)
                nextlevel.append(parent.right)
        level = nextlevel
    return root
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: It helped me a lot thanks. +1.  I was looking for this answer :)